# How to copy a number with full decimal precision from excel to DataGridView using Regex

Tags: c#

My code:

```
string[] pastedRows = Regex.Split(o.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString()
                           .TrimEnd("\r\n".ToCharArray()), "\r\n");
```

The data in Excel is visible as `2.1` but actually the value is `2.1459`. The above command is not helping me to write `2.1459` in `DatagridView`.

Comment: I also do not want user to achieve this by formatting to higher number of decimal places using  number formatting

Comment: Please [edit] that clarification into your post.  It's unclear what your additional restriction means.

Comment: If the cell value is 2.1459 but its display format is setup as 1.2 then that's the value that will be copied to the clipboard.  To get the actual value use Office Interop & read it directly, the clipboard is not suited for accurate interchange.

Comment: There is also no need for a RegEx in your current code

Comment: Thanks Alex for your valuable insight and suggestions. It has really helped me to understand. Also  Thanks to ryanyuyu, will follow your advice. Regds